# JavaFX chart origin coordinates

Tags: charts, javafx, position, coordinates

So I'm trying to figure out how JavaFX coordinate systems work, and get the coordinates of the origin point of a ScatterChart. I'm working on a video/animation editor and I've decided to make the timeline using a ScatterChart where the nodes are media(images, videos or audio) dragged to it (similar to Windows Movie Maker). The ScatterChart is **placed within a ScrollPane** so that the user can zoom and pan the timeline. 
To display the line indicating the player position I need the **coordinates of the start and the end** of the timeline, so that I could add a Line to the Pane in the background of the chart.
I can't seem to get the coordinates of the origin, no matter what I try.[image]

I tried to get the x Axis and find its position on the chart, but it doesn't work. I even tried adding a point to the chart and find its node's position, but that gives a 0, 0 position as well.

```
xAxis.localToParent(0,0) // prints 0, 0
xAxis.localToScene(0,0) // prints 0, 0
xAxis.localToScreen(0,0) // gives null
```

Could anyone provide a solution and perhaps an explanation of how coordinates in JavaFX are calculated?

Comment: It looks like you are calling those methods before layout has been performed. You need to call them after the `xAxis` has been added to scene, placed in a window, and the window displayed on the screen.

Comment: I am calling those functions in the initialization method, after the series with the axes has been added to the graph. I even tried to add chart data with a Circle (radius 1) and get its position, but all of the following calls:
`start.getNode().getBoundsInLocal()
start.getNode().localToScene(start.getNode().getBoundsInLocal(), true);
parent.sceneToLocal(boundsInScene)`
result in the following output:
`[minX:-1.0, minY:-1.0, minZ:0.0, width:2.0, height:2.0, depth:0.0, maxX:1.0, maxY:1.0, maxZ:0.0]`

Comment: Well, that's exactly my point. You can hardly expect to get the location of something on the screen before it has been placed on the screen.

Comment: It's also interesting that a MouseClick handler with event.getX() gives me the exact coordinate I need, about 63.0, and trying to programatically replicate that yields no results.

Comment: Again, it will only work once the node has been displayed on the screen. Clearly that is the case in a mouse handler (since it is invoked when the user clicks on it); but it will not work in the initialize method, because that is necessarily called when the UI is initialized, and before it is displayed.

Comment: You were right, thank you. I will post the solution below so that anyone having similar issues doesn't waste two days combing through the rest of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding chart data, one point at the start of the graph, X coordinate 0. This point's node is a Circle with a radius of 0 or 1, this is what I use for getting the X coordinate of the graph start. The function for getting this offset is:

```
Bounds boundsInScene = point.getNode().localToScene(point.getNode().getBoundsInLocal(), true);
return parent.sceneToLocal(boundsInScene).getMinX();
```

The parent is the Chart itself. The end coordinate can be acquired simply by adding the start offset to the result of the getValueForDisplay function with the max X coordinate as the argument.